# How to create Column Identifiers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm confused by [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#select) where it states:

> Columns are referenced by the identifiers (not by labels). For example, in a Google Spreadsheet, **column identifiers are the one or two character column letter (A, B, C, ...).**

Then directly proceeds to show some examples...

```
select *
```

```
select dept, salary
```

Neither of which appear to be *column identifiers* as defined.

It further goes on to to [define Identifiers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#identifiers)

> Identifiers (or IDs) are text strings that identify columns.

Which seems contradictory unless they are making a distinction between default identifiers and *custom* identifiers?

So, how does one *create* an identifier?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to *create* identifiers. With the Google Sheets `query()` function, use column references like `A`, `B`, `C` when your query refers to a range, and `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` when the query refers to a computed array such as `importrange()`.

The examples given at the help page are generic. Google Visualization Query Language is used by many other products besides Google Sheets.